Problem measuring car radio audio output with an oscilloscope
I am trying to use my Picoscope oscilloscope to measure the output signal of a car radio.
I am able to probe other points just fine in the radio and get a signal, but the main audio out does not seem to display anything. I know it is there as it is coming through the speakers, yet when I connect my probe to the solder joint where the output pin for the front left speaker (for example) goes to on the PCB, I get nothing. I have tried connecting the ground of the probe to the radio case, car ground, and the ground for the front left speaker output (FL-), yet nothing shows up. I am able to probe other points inside the radio, like the pre-amp, without ground, just fine.
What am I doing wrong?
See diagram below.


Oscilloscope input has two terminals, ground, and signal. Where is your ground?

Show us what you mean by "nothing shows up". Is your picoscope waiting for a trigger that never arrives? Can you manually force a trigger to make it sample?

Even with no trigger set there is no signal at all, just flat 0v.

The output likely is from a bridge amplifier, which is not referenced to ground.
Since most automotive systems are 12 VDC, and loudspeakers are commonly 4 or 8 Ω, maximum power would be limited to 36 or 18 W. The bridge effectively doubles output voltage, quadrupling output power.
Measure voltage across the speaker leads. If a speaker is not connected, place a 4 or 8 Ω resistor across the output.

Depending on if the car radio is being powered with an isolated or earth-referenced supply, it may be a bad idea to connect a scope ground lead to speaker terminal. With a floating supply it should be OK.

Am I not effectively already measuring voltage across the speaker leads by connecting the probe ground to the front left speaker - terminal?

@S.Stevens Do you have a speaker connected and can verify that you have actual output?

@S.Stevens You are not telling how you are powering the radio. The speaker negative output terminal is not ground so there is a possibility of damage if you connect scope GND to it. It depends on your power supply and other connections.
